# Select connection for VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have a laptop connected to internet through a cable and through WiFi. I also have a Windows VPN connection configured.  Because of the VPN server configuration, I have to connect to it using the local cable connection, and when I have wireless off it works correctly. But when I have both wireless and cable connections on, the VPN fails as it apparently try to use the wireless one.

Is there something I can change in my local configuration so the VPN prioritizes the local cable connection over the WiFi?

My current workaround is to disable WiFi, connect to the VPN and then re-enable WiFi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prioritize network connections by doing the following.

1. Open up `Network and Sharing center`
2. Click on `Change adapter settings`
3. Hit `ALT`
4. Go to the advanced menu
   [image]
5. Now you can order your network connections. The more higher your network adapter is, the more Windows will prioritize it.
   [image: LAN order]

This image is from Windows XP but should look more or less the same in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we solved the problem with this change in the adapter.

1. Open Device Manager
2. Open up Network Adapters and double-click your Wireless WLAN Adapter.
3. Under the Advanced Tab, click VLAN Priority Support (or Priority and Vlan)  and select Disable from the drop-down menu under Value:.
4. Click OK and test again.

Comment: I don't have that option under advanced settings. The WiFi card that I am using is Intel WiFi Link 5100 AGN with latest drivers.